# cómo puedo realizar bitacora de movimientos que registre los insert, update, delete que realicen el usuario que inicio sesion

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo 4 tablas vinculadas

Estoy utilizando phpMyadmin
|  usuario  |
|:---------:|
|id_usuario |
|descripcion|

| material |
| --- |
| cod_material |
| descripcion |
| cod_usu |

| entradas | salidas |
| --- | --- |
| cod_entradas | cod_salidas |
| fecha_entra | fecha_sali |
| personal | personal_c |
| cod_materi | cod_material |
| cant_entra | cant_sale |
| cod_usuregi | cod_usus |

Cómo puedo guardar los movimientos(editar,registrar,eliminar) que realice el usuario en una tabla llamada bitacora de movimientos

Comment: Una opción interesante sería programar disparadores (TRIGGER) que inserten en una tabla las inserciones, eliminaciones o actualizaciones de esas tablas. Si sólo deben registrarse para un determinado usuario o grupo de usuarios, pondrías un criterio para controlarlo. Para más detalles sobre los TRIGGER, puedes consultar [este tutorial](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/) u otros en la red.

Comment: @Alex17 Debes aportar el código de lo que has intentado para que podamos ayudarte...

Comment: @Alex17 quieres saber los movimientos(editar,registrar,eliminar), o lo que quieres saber son los datos que envían los usuarios al hacer esos movimientos?

Comment: Deberías controlarlo en todos los casos inserción update o delete y al finalizar tu proceso debes hacer una inserción en la tabla bitacora (mas adecuada sería ``logs``), en dicha tabla debes definir los campos fecha, accion...etc.., e id del usuario el cual lo obtendrás desde la variable $_SESSION que previamente debes haber definido en el ingreso al sistema.